# RDLC exported table align to right in excel sheet c#

Tags: rdlc

Can any one help me for align table generated through `RDLC` in excel to right align for Arabic user point of view

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the cell content? Any sample screenshot?

Comment: yes i have screenshot not about cell complete table i need to right to left i am attaching a screenshot so please need some help in thi.

Comment: @HardcoreGamer need your assistance actually excel report generated through rdlc is left to right in excel so for Arabic user point of view i want to align Right to left to whole table i tried with ClosedXml but its not working properly.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what's your current issue. Is the image you show me right aligned (Expected Result)? What is the current result?

Comment: this sheet is left align by default when exported from rdlc but i want to show this sheet from right to left in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can change text alignment from textbox properties.

1 Select Column with alignment to be changed.
2 Press <kbd>F4</kbd> or expand properties.
3 Change Text Alignment.

[image: Change RDLC text Alignment]

Comment: @Market , Mark this as answer if this worked.